# Cannot update product quantity stored in MongoDB, using Node.js and React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a warehouse management site. I have the data stored in MongoDB. I want the product quantity to be updated on a button click and show it on the UI. But after updating the quantity, when I console log it I get undefined.

This is the function to decrease the quantity on click and update it on DB:

```js
const ProductDetail = () => {
    const { productId } = useParams();
    const [product] = useProductDetail(productId);
    const { _id, name, img, description, supplier, price, quantity } = product;

    const [updatedQuantity, setUpdatedQuantity] = useState(quantity);


    const handleDecreaseQuantity = (id) => {

        const { quantity, ...rest } = product;
        const previousQuantity = quantity;
        setUpdatedQuantity(previousQuantity - 1)
        const updatedProduct = { updatedQuantity, ...rest }

        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/updateProduct/${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(updatedProduct)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
        console.log(updatedQuantity);

    }
```

This is product update API:

```js
app.put('/updateProduct/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const updatedProduct = req.body;
            const { updatedQuantity } = updatedProduct;
            const id = req.params.id;
            const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
            const options = { upsert: true };

            const updateProduct = {
                $set: {
                    quantity: updatedQuantity
                },
            };

            const result = await productCollection.updateOne(query, updateProduct, options);
            console.log(result);

            res.send(result);

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
> pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
> method can potentially return the existing value.   There is no
> guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
> be batched for performance gains.

This part of the code might not be executing as you think.

```
const previousQuantity = quantity;
setUpdatedQuantity(previousQuantity - 1);
const updatedProduct = { updatedQuantity, ...rest };
```

Update your product quantity and send it to API. By the action is completed, your state also might be updated.

```
const previousQuantity = quantity;
const updatedProduct = { updatedQuantity: previousQuantity - 1, ...rest };
setUpdatedQuantity(previousQuantity - 1);
```

Comment: Now, the issue is  when I set the quantity as initial value of the updatedQuantity state, it shows nothing on the UI. I destructured the quantity from product object which I am getting from API.

Comment: `const [updatedQuantity, setUpdatedQuantity] = useState(quantity)` Isn't that setting as initial value?

Comment: No, when I want to show updatedQuantity on the UI, it renders nothing.